# Resources for building a custom event page template

Tags: plugins, customization, page-template

I'm new to Wordpress.  I've set up a few simple custom themes, and have found it generally pretty intuitive.   I have a client that would like to be able to manage their own site content so I'm looking into how to convert their site to Wordpress, and I'm having trouble finding the fix for my specific layout.  I think I may not be asking the appropriate questions, so please help a brother out.

I'd like to be able to create a new version of this page using Wordpress: 
[Theatre-Hikes - A Midsummer Night's Dream](https://kshewey.github.io/Theatre-Hikes/midsummer.html)

For when the company has new events (like next season when they have a whole new list of plays they're producing).  The layout would be exactly the same, just including new pictures and changing the info.  Can anyone point me in the direction of resources/tutorials that can get me where I need to go?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed your themes and plugins and know your way around them, you might need next:

- to customize the theme chosen with your own code: use a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)
- install an events manager plugin: [The Events Calendar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/) could work for you, if not go ahead and check any other plugin with the [events tag](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/events/)
- if you still need more resources, [WP Codex has a pretty good How To page](https://codex.wordpress.org/New_To_WordPress_-_Where_to_Start), pointing to lots of useful pages

Comment: I think I'm specifically looking for a plugin that would create an entire new page for an individual event, as opposed to one of the plugins that's just a calendar.  If there isn't one built, I'd be happy to code my own, but I was hoping for a tutorial suggestion in plugin building if that's the case.

Comment: Take a look at this event page: http://www.sanluisobispocollection.com/calendar/jazz-brunch-sunny-wright-2/

If this is what you would like, this site is using https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/ + their PRO add on. I'm not sure about the addition the PRO plugin brings, you'll need to check their docs for yourself.